# python: adding a zero if my value is less then 3 digits long

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that needs to add a zero in front of the number if its less than 4 digits.

I only have to update a particular row:

```
import csv
f = open('csvpatpos.csv')
 csv_f = csv.reader(f) 
 for row in csv_f:
    print row[5]
```

then I want to parse through that row and add a 0 to the front of any number that is shorter than 4 digits.  And then input it into a new csv file with the adjusted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will read in the given `csv` file, iterate through each row and each item in each row, and output it to a new `csv` file.

```
import csv
import os

f = open('csvpatpos.csv')

# open temp .csv file for output
out = open('csvtemp.csv','w')

csv_f = csv.reader(f) 
for row in csv_f:
    # create a temporary list for this row
    temp_row = []

    # iterate through all of the items in the row
    for item in row:
        # add the zero filled value of each temporary item to the list
        temp_row.append(item.zfill(4))
    # join the current temporary list with commas and write it to the out file
    out.write(','.join(temp_row) + '\n')
out.close()
f.close()
```

Your results will be in `csvtemp.csv`. If you want to save the data with the original filename, just add the following code to the end of the script

```
# remove original file
os.remove('csvpatpos.csv')

# rename temp file to original file name
os.rename('csvtemp.csv','csvpatpos.csv')
```

**Pythonic Version**

The code above is is very verbose in order to make it understandable. Here is the code refactored to make it more [Pythonic](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html)

```
import csv

new_rows = []
with open('csvpatpos.csv','r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_f:
        row = [ x.zfill(4) for x in row ]
        new_rows.append(row)

with open('csvpatpos.csv','wb') as f:
    csv_f = csv.writer(f)
    csv_f.writerows(new_rows)
```

Comment: Wow, thats awesome, its not working so far but I need to change a few things I think.  I'm getting stuck here out.write(','.join(temp_row) + '\n').

Comment: I do not, I understand the second part.  However, I need to specify row[5].  Not sure where to place that? I'm fairly new at Python and I'm trying to learn it by jumping in and performing the code.

Comment: Is there any reason that all numbers can't have the extra 0s? And since you're new at this, let me make sure I'm clear. When you say row[5] do you mean the 5th or the 6th row? Because Python lists use [Zero-based numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), (or indexing, in this case) as do most programming languages. So row[5] actually addresses the 6th row because row[0] is the initial row. This is done because in binary the first combination in the powers of 2 is 0 (e.g. 0000=0, 0001=1, 0010=2, 0011=3, ... , 1111 = 15)

Comment: I actually have that row correct, because I do understand that the first row is zero. When I was trying to write the program I thought it would need an if statement. Because the digits within row 5 will need to have 4 digits total anything below I will need to add a zero at the end so that it matches up with what the customer has.  So if it comes in with two I will need to add two zero's.

Comment: Then I need to add the adjusted row and send it back to the customer which is automated as well.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use string formatting for these things:

```
>>> '{:04}'.format(99)
'0099'
```

[Format String Syntax documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: -1: `then I want to **parse** through that row and add a 0 to the front of any number that is shorter than 4 digits` I don't see how it answers the question

Answer (score 2):

When you think about parsing, you either need to think about [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) or [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). In this case, `regex` would perform the parsing quite easily.

But that's not all, once you are able to parse the numbers, you need to zero fill it. For that purpose, you need to use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for padding and justifying the string accordingly.

Consider your string

```
st = "parse through that row and add a 0 to the front of any number that is shorter than 4 digits."
```

In the above lines, you can do something like

**Implementation**

```
parts = re.split(r"(\d{0,3})", st)
''.join("{:>04}".format(elem) if elem.isdigit() else elem for elem in parts)
```

**Output**

```
'parse through that row and add a 0000 to the front of any number that is shorter than 0004 digits.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Will leave you with two hints:

```
s = "486"
s.isdigit() == True
```

for finding what things are numbers.

And

```
s = "486"
s.zfill(4) == "0486"
```

for filling in zeroes.

Comment: `then I want to **parse** through that row and add a 0 to the front of any number that is shorter than 4 digits` I don't see how it answers the question

Comment: The s variable will never be the same.  So I don't know how this would work.